# How to get self pod with kubernetes client-go

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I have a kubernetes service, written in Go, and am using `client-go` to access the kubernetes apis.

I need the `Pod` of the service's own pod.

The `PodInterface` allows me to iterate all pods, but what I need is a "self" concept to get the currently running pod that is executing my code.

It appears by reading `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace` and searching pods in the namespace for the one matching `hostname`, I can determine the "self" pod.

Is this the proper solution?

Answer (score 3):

Expose the `POD_NAME` and `POD_NAMESPACE` to your pod as environment variables. Later use those values to get your own pod object.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_POD_NAME MY_POD_NAMESPACE;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
  restartPolicy: Never
```

**Ref:** [environment-variable-expose-pod-information](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/)